# SQLite read from SQLITE database in plugin

Tags: sqlite, firefox, plugins, database-connection

I need to read values from an SQLite database in my plugin. For that I found the `sqlite.jsm` module. My problem is I want to make a row as a global variable, but the code used in SQLite (promises and tasks) is asynchronous. Is there a way I can collect information from my database into a global variable?

```js
let iDs = [];

Task.spawn(function* () {
    let db = yield Sqlite.openConnection({ path:
                                          permissionFilePath});

    try {
        let row = yield db.execute(
            "SELECT id FROM 'moz_hosts'");

        for ( i=0; i < row.length; i++) {
            console.log("row["+ i +"] :" +
                        row[i].getResultByIndex(0));
            yield iDs.push(row[i].getResultByIndex(0));
        }
    }
    finally {
        yield db.close();
    }
});

// Part of the code that doesn't work, because IDs are not yet assigned any values!
console.log("debug");
for (i=0; i<iDs.length; i++) {
  yield console.log("iDs ["+i+"] = "+ iDs[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, for a Task you only have to yield things that return promises and therefore run asynchronously. There is no need to `yield iDs.push(row[i].getResultByIndex(0));`, because the push operation will synchronously return the new length of the array. This shouldn't be much of an issue for the code itself though.

Do you really need the ids to be global? Maybe you can refactor your code so that you don't need to save them globally.

If this is not an option, you will have to block all operations that are going to access the ids until the SQL call has completed. You can do this by relying on the fact that Task.spawn() itself will also return a promise. This also has the nice side effect that you don't need the extra global array:

```
let idsPromise = Task.spawn(function*() {
    let ids = [];
    let db = yield Sqlite.openConnection({ path: permissionFilePath});

    try {
        let row = yield db.execute("SELECT id FROM 'moz_hosts'");
        for (let i = 0, len = row.length; i < len; i++) {
            ids.push(row[i].getResultByIndex(0));
        }
        // Instead of the loop you can also use:
        // ids = row.map(row => row.getResultByIndex(0));
    } finally {
        yield db.close();
    }

    return ids;
});
```

Then, in other parts of your code, when you want the ids you can use:

```
idsPromise.then(function(ids) {
    // Do something with ids
});
```

Alternatively, you can also get them in a Task:

```
Task.spawn(function*() {
    let ids = yield idsPromise;
});
```

You can do this multiple times. Once a promise is resolved the `then()` part will be executed as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot.